# In R markdown html output, how do we ensure that the font type and size of inline code and params match the rest of the text?

Tags: r, r-markdown

While creating an R markdown report, after I knit, the font of the auto populated works and numbers in the text show up in a different font and are highlighted in gray which makes it took different from the rest of the document. How do I fix this?

I tried setting the font type and size in the top yml part of the markdown but this did not work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ashna J! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Rmarkdown in a question can be even more difficult to format well, because the way Stack does [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) looks very similar. For that, I suggest pasting the raw (reduced, _minimal reprex_) rmarkdown document into the question (yaml header, backtick code chunks, and all), highlight all of it, then press `Ctrk-K` to _indent_ it all. The formatted form should look much better after this.